# Java Script Web Socket client is not working

Tags: javascript, php, websocket

I'm developing php webpage And I want to use web socket.I developed a javascript web socket client.And I developed a websocket using java.Locally web socket client is working well.But when hosted, it is not working.My wen Socket is working well.When web page run locally,I use hosted java web socket and It is working well. 
this is my javacript web socket client

```
var INIT_WS = "ws://184.72.171.96:9059/";

function openwebsocket(uname){

                if(webSocket !== undefined && webSocket.readyState !== WebSocket.CLOSED){
                   writeResponse("WebSocket is already opened.");
                    return;
                }
                webSocket = new WebSocket(INIT_WS + "Sl2World/slworldendpoint/"+uname);

                webSocket.onopen = function(event){
                    if(event.data === undefined)
                        return; 
                    writeResponse(event.data);
                };

                webSocket.onmessage = function(event){

                    writeResponse(event.data);                    
                }; 
                webSocket.onclose = function(event){
                    writeResponse("Connection closed");
                }; 
           }
```

When php web page hosted,Why it is not working.In that case I can't get any error message.I thing web socket connection request is not going to java web socket.
thank you.

Comment: This more than likely has to do with how your remote server is configured - how are you hosting your remote Java code?

Comment: Remote java project  is a standard java web application.Anyway it is working fine when it is called by the php project locally.

Comment: Okay. How and where is your PHP hosted? Some hosts don't allow WebSocket connections, while others do.

Comment: Can we change host's configuration to allow WebSocket connection?

Comment: That entirely depends upon the host and what kind of hosting it is, thus my question.

Comment: yes,I change the server and it allow websocket connection.thank you @spirulence

Answer (score 0):

This would appear to be a security configuration issue on the host. While your local PHP file connects without a problem this will be because of a network firewall issue on your hosts network which would not affect a PHP file running on the same network. Most web hosts will not support websockets at this point due to their environments not being designed for them yet. Your best bet would be to find a host which specifically allows websockets and then ask them what socket numbers are allowed, or set up your own virtual or dedicated machine to run your java application.